# Terraform: How to force a resource to be Destroyed and Recreated

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am deploying a resource: **aws_ssm_document**. It creates properly. If I modify the **content** or **attachments_source** property terraform sees that and proposes the resource "*will be updated in-place*".

Unfortunately, **aws_ssm_document** cannot be updated:

```
│ Error: Error updating SSM document: InvalidParameterValueException: AttachmentsSource not provided in the input request.
│       status code: 400, request id: 78de3d42-b2b6-4dcf-8bd2-590490a1e4ea
```

What I want to do is:

1. disable updating this document
2. then I can use lifecycle to force a
   Destroy-Then-Create scenario.

I do not want to use taint, because we don't know when the resources is actually tainted on a run. Is there a resource that can taint another resource? If I could create additional document versions, I think that would address the problem.

My Document:

```
{
    "schemaVersion": "2.0",
    "version": "${random_uuid.xxx.id}",
    "packages": {
        "windows": {
            "_any": {
                "_any": {
                    "file": "xxx.zip"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "files": {
        "xxx.zip": {
            "checksums": { 
                "sha256":  "${ filesha256("../Infrastructure/xxx/xxx.zip") }"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an issue with the AWS provider for years that will also probably never be fixed because it only relates to version < 2.0 of the schema for SSM documents. You probably want to update to at least 2.0 to avoid this issue.

Comment: I included my document - I think I am using 2.0, however this really seems like a lifecycle issue.  I can force DestroyThenCreate; and there is a PreventDestroy property, but not a PreventUpdate property.

Comment: It is definitely a provider issue. The provider code could be modified to do all of this automatically and invoke a different CRUD resource function. Actually it appears a fix did happen at some point for this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/7516. However, I do recall using that version and still seeing the issue with version < 2.0. It may be that that actually something else is happening here.

Comment: As for doing this outside the provider, there is no `DestroyThenCreate` lifecycle meta-argument according to the doc: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#syntax-and-arguments. If you want to do this outside the provider, then you have to use `replace=` argument or the former `taint` subcommand which you stated you did not want to do.

Comment: There is a lifecycle argument to force a Destroy to happen before a Create does - according to docs. What is missing is a NoUpdate property.